# RSA Key Blinding

Tags: rsa, reference-request, timing-attack, blinding

I was looking the answer to the following question ([Timing attack on modular exponentiation](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/6538/timing-attack-on-modular-exponentiation)), discussing the Private Key Blinding as a countermeasure for timing attacks.

Therefore I'm asking if someone could point me to a reference for the presented algorithm and if there are other alternatives to implement Key Blinding.